# Should the site be (hopefully :) enriched with legal questions from Politics.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

Politics.SE (Beta site) has had the distinction of the closest site to "law.se" for a while, until Law.SE went into BETA recently.

As such, it accumulated several questions that were more Law than Politics - some fully offtopic and closed, some kinda-offtopic but clearly better answerable by Law experts.

Is there any appetite to trawl through Politics.SE and import some of the better-quality law related questions from there? (either via migration, or copy/paste, or in some cases rewording).

Answer (score 4):

Wow, something along these lines seems to come up on a lot of beta sites on the early days (e.g. [HSM](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220/do-we-want-to-have-all-new-hsm-type-questions-from-other-se-sites-migrated-here) and [its counterpart on Mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19699/migrating-questions-to-hsm)).

You clearly know more about Politics than I do, so the specifics should be left to someone more in the know than me. But I can bring up some things that are *always* brought up when this question comes up:

## Don't migrate things here that fit in fine over there.

Questions can be on topic on multiple sites. This happens quite a bit. For example, there are questions about [physical-chemistry](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry) on Chemistry that would be fine on Physics. This is just fine.

If a question is well-received on Politics - or is received decently at all - **it should be left there.** We had a large problem on HSM when History decided to migrate two questions to us that already had great answers and lots of votes. This led to a meta post on each site, a follow-up months later when someone saw that the versions on HSM hadn't been deleted (we did not accept the migration) and then a post on Meta Stack Exchange about the general situation. Not good. Not good at all.

> As such, it accumulated several questions that were more Law than Politics - some fully offtopic and closed, some kinda-offtopic but clearly better answerable by Law experts.

The fully off-topic, closed ones could be migrated here. The kinda-off-topic ones are a bit dubious. There would have to be a clear consensus that a question is better on Law.

I also notice that less than ten [law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) questions were asked on Politics in the last 60 days, meaning that less than ten of those are available for migration (there are more than don't use that tag, preferring [international-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-law) or something related, so increasing the total) - perhaps 25 law-related questions. Give or take. It also doesn't seem like the majority have been poorly received. I see a lot of accepted answers.

I have nothing against migrating some questions here. But they would have to be **clearly off-topic** on Politics, **clearly on-topic** on Law, less than 60 days old, and good questions (I refer to the ["Don't Migrate Crap"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446) policy).

Comment: Most of the "kinda ontopic" ones were basically left there out of lack of options. E.g. they were 10% ontopic there and 90% here, from my recollection. Most certainly there was no situation of "100% on topic on both"

Comment: @DVK Oh, good, that sounds clear enough.

Comment: We've definitely had at least one that was closed on Politics last year as off-topic (I know because I VTCed on Politics and answered it here). In general, Politics has been fine with questions that aren't *purely* "how's this law work" (the one I'm talking about was "given this conflict between two old laws, which one took precedence").